# Geting files out bad hard drive

Tags: boot, hard-drive, live-usb

I had xubuntu on my notebook. The screen went black and I had to shut it down. Turning it on I receive this message:

> Pri Master hard disk: S.M.A.R.T Status BAD, Backup and Replace

I looked up the error and it seems I have to use a new hard disk. My big concern though is my files ...

I have access to a Windows 7 desktop and a slow Internet connection. My notebook does not have a CD/DVD drive so I guess my only hope would be booting the notebook from a USB stick. [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), I found a guide that shows how a bootable USB can be created in Windows.

My question is, as my Internet is slow, what is the smallest Linux Disto I can use on the USB that allows me boot my notebook and to access/save my files on the hard disk? I think the file system I used was Ext2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know basically of two Linux distributions with VERY little image sizes:

- [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org/) which needs only about 90MB for its  boot image on your USB, or
- [DSL (DamnSmallLinux)](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) which says it runs from a 50MB image.

I never used one of those so I can't tell you which of them is more comfortable to use, but I think both of them should be enough for a rescue job. I hope you have fun with them. ;D Greetings and good luck!